# Convert HTML to a json file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, e-commerce

I am working on an e-commerce website and i need to extract all product information such as product name, price, and product description into json format but I do not know how to do that. Below is a sample code of a row of products.

```
<div class='cakes'>
    <div class='col-3'>
        <img src = 'Images/banana cake.jpg'>
        <h4>Banana Cake</h4>
        <p>&#8373;30</p>
        <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
        <img src = 'Images/pastry_box_1.jpg'>
        <h4>Pastry Box</h4>
        <p>Mini: &#8373;35 | Midi: &#8373;50 | Maxi: &#8373;90</p>
        <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3'>
        <img src = 'Images/cupcakes_12.jpg'>
        <h4>Cupcakes</h4>
        <p>Box of 4: &#8373;30 |  Box of 12: &#8373;85 | Box of 6: &#8373;40</p>
        <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
```

I need to extract the various details about each product into .a json file for my JavaScript code but I am unsure how to go about it. I am using VS code and from the tutorial video I am using there is already a .json file with all product information but it isn't mentioned how it was created and I can't follow through because of that.

Comment: You're describing "web scraping."  Web scraping is a skill that you'll need to learn to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird you do not have the JSON that created the cart

But here it is

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".cakes div")].map(div => {
  const title = div.querySelector("h4").textContent;
  const img = div.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src");
  const text = div.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
  return {
    title,
    text,
    img
  }
})

const JSONString = JSON.stringify(elements)
console.log(JSONString)
```

```html
<div class='cakes'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <img src='Images/banana cake.jpg'>
    <h4>Banana Cake</h4>
    <p>&#8373;30</p>
    <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <img src='Images/pastry_box_1.jpg'>
    <h4>Pastry Box</h4>
    <p>Mini: &#8373;35 | Midi: &#8373;50 | Maxi: &#8373;90</p>
    <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <img src='Images/cupcakes_12.jpg'>
    <h4>Cupcakes</h4>
    <p>Box of 4: &#8373;30 | Box of 12: &#8373;85 | Box of 6: &#8373;40</p>
    <button class='add-to-cart' data-id='1'>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is code will be helpful in extracting the data i need but how do i extract and save it as a .json file? do i need to run the code in the main javascript file? and what code would i need to export it to .json?

Comment: It is json and you can run it after load of the page. If you need to save it on the server, you can Ajax it to their server and read it with a server process